# jQuery Mobile and Select menu with URLs

Tags: jquery, url, select, mobile, menu

Been battling with this for a while now. I'm trying to get a select menu to work as a navigation menu but I cannot get the URLs to work and have it actually change pages.

In the head:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($("#select-choice-1"));
    });        
});
</script>
```

With this Menu:

```
<div id="MobileWrapper" data-role="fieldcontain">
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-theme="a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" data-mini="true">
<option data-placeholder="true">Navigation</option><!-- data=placeholder makes this not show up in the pop up-->
<option value="/index.php" data-ajax="false">Home</option>
<option value="/services/index.php" data-ajax="false">Services</option>
<option value="/trainers/index.php" data-ajax="false">Trainers</option>
<option value="/locations/index.php" data-ajax="false">Locations</option>
<option value="/calendar/index.php" data-ajax="false">Calendar</option>
<option value="/contactus/index.php" data-ajax="false">Contact Us</option>
</select>
</div><!--END MobileWrapper DIV-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).val());
    });        
});
```

you were telling jQuery mobile to change to the dropdown menu everytime the user clicked the dropdown menu.

`.change` is only triggered when a new option is selected from the dropdown and `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected item.

**Update**

The aforementioned solution fixed part of the problem, but the navigation was still not working because...

The navigation URLs were being resolved to `http://www.domain.com/...` and the page loads under `http://domain.com/...` and jQuery mobile prevents cross domain pages by default.

There are a few solutions (untested)

1. Add a base tag in the document head
   `<base href="http://domain.com/" />`
2. Allow crossDomainPages in jQuery by setting the following before the DOM is ready
   `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true`

Comment: It tries. But it just doesn't go anywhere. If I click on nav item the jQuery "I'm thinking" spinning icon comes up, but it never switches pages. Could it be the data-ajax stuff?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it should work, it's probably something else. Can you provide a link to the page(s) you are working on?

Comment: http://kickfitness.com/services/index2.php#.UM1xfaXCJ4E It's done with responsive CSS, so if you size your screen small enough the mobile nav pops up.

Comment: Any other thoughts why this navigation isn't working? I'd really like to keep it in a Select menu so that it takes up little of the screen. Or if there is a way in jQuery mobile to make an expandable menu, I'd be open to trying that.

Comment: Found the solution and updated my answer! It was a sneaky little bug.

Comment: Somebody? Anybody? Bueller? Bueller? I really need to fix this.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the issue is, just not how to solve it. I need to add data-ajax="false" to the script somehow. I did this, but syntax is wrong:<script>
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage(($(this).val()) + data-ajax="false");
    });        
});
</script>

Comment: So I somehow need to add the data-ajax="false" to the changePage script.

Comment: thanks for your help, but your solution isn't working. I really think it has to do with Ajax, because I discovered the links weren't working on the page when it was in a larger browser and displayed without the select menu. I added data-ajax="false" to the nav links on the PC version and they now work. So then I have tried multiple ways of disabling Ajax. None seem to work. This is the latest code in the HEAD:

Comment: <base href="http://kickfitness.com/" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
/* VERY IMPORTANT this is before loading jquery.mobile JS */
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).val());
    });        
});
</script>

Comment: I also changed the URL values back to /services/index.php. I had changed them to the http://www.kickfitness.com/... Really at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is when I click the Navigation button it goes to: http://kickfitness.com/services/index2.php#&ui-state=dialog Not sure if this is what it is supposed to do or not. Then I click a button and goes back to the regular services URL.

Comment: I just noticed when I rollover a option button the browser window has Go to "http://kickfitness.com/#" I have tried to disable ajax, not sure if I have been successful.

Comment: Now you are getting an "unrecognized expression: `window.history.back()`" error. You've changed a lot since asking the original question and changing the urls to point to domain.com instead of www.domain.com did fix the original problem. Unfortunately, I don't have time to chase all the bugs that pop up on your site. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: So I should have my links as the complete domain? http://www.kickfitness.com? I didn't change that much. I added ajax disabling, and the code you suggested. I'm at loss on how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but if I switch to an early version of jQuery mobile, my menu works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```